# Regular expression that checks on exactly one occurrence of several possible strings

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression for an regularexpressionvalidator control where an input field must contain exactly 1 of:

"youtube.com/watch?v=" OR "vimeo.com/" OR "youtu.be/"

If any of these strings occur more than once or not at all, the expression should fail so I can notify the user.

Comment: If the strings can appear anywhere in the field then a regex to do this would be extremely clumsy. You would have to write an alternation that checked for each of the possibilities, preceded and followed by neither of the others. Far better to describe the possibilities for the *entire contents* of the field. Would that be possible? It looks like you want to match a URL from one of three sites, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not required here!

you can use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method

---

Or if you need regex

```
^.*?(youtube\.com/watch\?v\=|vimeo\.com/|youtu\.be/).*$
```

Comment: I'm afraid a regex *is* required for a `regularexpressionvalidator` control!